# How do I combination two lists in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have two sets of identical structures. I want to combine them by id field.
The combination should be made on a specific field (for l1 Num2 and for l2 Num1) All other fields should not be changed.

```
  List<MyClass> l1=[{id = 1 , num1 = 3 , num2 = 0 , name = "yoyo"},
                      {id = 2 , num1 = 9 , num2 = 0 , name = "lolo"},
                      {id = 3 , num1 = 4 , num2 = 0 , name = "bobo"},
                      {id = 8 , num1 = 2 , num2 = 0 , name = "toto"}];

    List<MyClass> l2=[{id = 1 , num1 = 0 , num2 = 3 , name = "yoyo"}, 
                      {id = 2 , num1 = 0 , num2 = 7 , name = "lolo"},
                      {id = 3 , num1 = 0 , num2 = 8 , name = "bobo"},
                      {id = 6 , num1 = 0 , num2 = 7 , name = "zozo"}];

  //  i want to combine the lists to get l3 like this one
    list<MyClass> l3=[{id = 1 , num1 = 3 , num2 = 3 , name = "yoyo"}, 
                      {id = 2 , num1 = 9 , num2 = 7 , name = "lolo"},
                      {id = 3 , num1 = 4 , num2 = 8 , name = "bobo"},
                      {id = 8 , num1 = 2 , num2 = 0 , name = "toto"},
                      {id = 6 , num1 = 0 , num2 = 7 , name = "zozo"}];
```

Comment: This would be easier if you use a Map where the "id field" was the key. This way merging would be just `map1.putAll(map2)` you could also do `map1.get(id)` and `map1.remove(id)`

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: you meant something like map<id,MyClass>   it will be overwritten if i have same id?

Comment: The tooltip for the "downvote" arrow says: _This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful._ Just saying.

Comment: `you meant something like` who _you_? If you want to address a commenter (and have her notified), include her name prefixed with a `@`(you will get suggestions). - `java.util.Map.put(id, value)` would _replace, returning the old mapping_ for (same) id. Then, there is [`Map.compute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l3.addall(l1);
for(int i=0;i<l2.size();i++){
   for(int j=0;j<l3.size();j++){
      if(l2.get(i).id!=l3.get(j).id)
          l3.add(l2.get(i);
      else{
         l3.get(j).num2=l2.get(i).num2;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: the code didn't work. this result recieved is a list size l2 x l1 and i need l3 to be with size of the longest list as max{l1,l2}.
but it is close to the right solution. I try to edit the answer so it will work fine but for some reason it didn't update

Comment: i accepted your answer because it's helped me to build the correct answer thank you.

Comment: it seems I didn't understand problem correctly but I'm glad if this code helped you

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to use java 8 streams API, e.g.:

```
  l1.addAll(l2.stream().filter(
                            mc -> !l1.stream().anyMatch(
                            mcl1 -> mcl1.id==mc.id))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Here, you can try this out, it changes for me:

```
    List<MyClass> l1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new MyClass[]{new MyClass(1,1),new MyClass(2,2)}));
    List<MyClass> l2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new MyClass[]{new MyClass(1,1),new MyClass(3,3)}));

    l1.addAll(l2.stream().filter(
            mc -> !l1.stream().anyMatch(
                    mcl1 -> mcl1.id==mc.id))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    l1.forEach(b -> System.out.println("id: " + b.getId() + " num1: " + b.getNum1()));
```

For explanation i'm using `l2.stream.filter` filters second list by not equals by id elements, `collect(Collectors.toList())` return result from filter as list, and `l1.addAll` adds returned elements to list. For this solution it prints for me:

```
id: 1 num1: 1
id: 2 num1: 2
id: 3 num1: 3
```

Comment: the code didn't work. it's seems like l1 didn't change at all. can you explain the code please

Comment: thank you for the update but if i understand you correctly. the code just added new record if it was not exist by id field. it's not what i look for . please see the example l3